# iTextSharp table not displayed in document

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I'm trying to create a simple PDF with header and table.
I create the document but the table is not displayed in the document.

I followed:
mikesdotnetting.com 
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/86/iTextSharp-Introducing-Tables

But for some reason it doesn't work for me.

I use the below code:

```
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
    Paragraph header = new Paragraph(new Phrase("some title"));
    Phrase phrase = new Phrase("dasdasdas");
    byte[] streamBytes;

    header.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    document.Open();
    document.Add(header);
    document.Add(table);

    table.AddCell("cell1");
    table.AddCell("cell2");

    document.Close();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding the table to the document before adding anything to it. You need to fully create the table *and then* add it to the document.

```
table.AddCell("cell1");
table.AddCell("cell2");

document.Add(table);
```

Comment: i thought the document constructs itself upon the call to close and thus the order doesn't matter... I was wrong... thanks!